# Suppose $ABCD$ is a cyclic quad and $BCDE$ is a cyclic quad as well, is it safe to conclude that $A$, $B$, $C$, $D$ and $E$ are concyclic?

Tags: geometry

Just a quick question.

suppose $ABCD$ is a cyclic quad and $BCDE$ is a cyclic quad as well, is it safe to conclude that $A$, $B$, $C$, $D$ and $E$ are concyclic?

Given that they have $3$ points in common, wouldn't it imply that the cyclic quad must lie in the circumcircle of triangle $BCD$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your statement is absolutely correct. Any three (distinct, noncolinear) points have a unique circle which passes through them, and so $A$ and $E$ must both lie on the circle that passes through $B$, $C$, and $D$.

Comment: Should "(distinct)" be "noncollinear"?

Comment: @JohnBentin Indeed, thank you. I have added that.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, because the circumscribed circumference of $\triangle BCD$ is unique